# Intercepting mouse clicks when the mouse is hovering above a control

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on a MFC C++ dialog where I need to respond to right mouse click events for a dialog even if the mouse is hovering over a control.

I could write event handler code for each control to delegate the work to the parent dialog, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution?

I'm hoping there is some way to intercept the windows messages, but I'm still figuring that part out. I've tried listening to the WM_COMMAND messages with Spy++ but I didn't see what I needed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up a hook to intercept mouse messages.  Take a look at [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`WH_MOUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28VS.85%29.aspx#wh_mousehook)